# Using defaultIfEmpty() still not emitting in Angular canActivate guard

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable in a service:

```
hasAccess$: Observable<boolean>;
```

This gets assigned in a separate component. It has `filter()` in it and will never emit false, only true. So if it's false it doesn't emit.

I need to use it in a route guard. So I tried:

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.service.hasAccess$.pipe(
      defaultIfEmpty(false),
      tap(access => {
        console.log({access}); // never logs
      }),
      first()
    );
  }
```

- I used `defaultIfEmpty()` to ensure a value is emitted
- I used `tap()` to log if anything happens (it doesn't)
- I used `first()` because observables returned in guards *must complete*.

I ensured `this.service.hasAccess$` gets assigned. It throws an error if it isn't because you can't pipe off undefined. There's no error. Now the weird thing is, this emits false:

```
return of().pipe(
  defaultIfEmpty(false),
  tap(access => {
    console.log({access});
  }),
  first()
);
```

Both are piped to `defaultIfEmpty(false)`. Why isn't the guard emitting?

**Update**: Thanks to @martin for pointing out that `defaultIfEmpty()` only emits on completion. Also I realize now that `first()` won't make it complete if it doesn't emit anything. I guess I need to figure out how to make it complete when it doesn't emit anything.

Comment: Is it working when hasAccess emits true? Maybe Im getting it wrong but if hasAccess is not emitting at all when the case is false how will subscriber know about it? So it has to emit something.

Comment: @talhature that's what defaultIfEmpty() is for

Comment: `defaultIfEmpty` emits only after its source completes. So are you sure `this.service.hasAccess$` always completes? If it's a Subject then it's very likely you never complete it.

Comment: @martin It doesn't complete (but it's not a Subject). I used `first()` to make it complete. I tried putting `defaultIfEmpty()` after `first()`, but that didn't work.

Comment: @martin also thanks for pointing out that defaultIfEmpty() only emits after completion.

Comment: first() will delay until the source emits or completes, though, so that's why it doesn't work. What you want to do cannot work logically: how should the pipe ever know whether a true will or won't come unless it actually waits for it? That's impossible.

Comment: @IngoBürk yea, see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a solution:

```
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.service.hasAccess$.pipe(
      merge(of(false)),
      first()
    );
  }
```

1. It starts by piping off of `hasAccess$`,
2. It merges with an observable of `false`,
3. It uses `first()` so that if `hasAccess$` emits true, it takes it, else if it emits nothing, the guard gets false.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `startWith(false)` operator to your `hasAccess$` observable, so it will always emit something:

```js
hasAccess$: Observable<boolean> = this.someServiceCall().pipe(startWith(false));
```

---

Or you can introduce a timeout in the `canActivate()` method:

```js
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.service.hasAccess$.pipe(
    timeout(5000),
    first(),
    catchError(() => of(false))
  );
}
```

---

If I were you, I'd use the first method if `hasAccess$` is getting its value from a store or a synchronous source, and method 2, if it is making an asynchronous call.

Comment: `startWith()` seems like a great solution. I would not consider the `timeout()`, I would never want to introduce a race condition or make my user wait.

Comment: Tried `startWith()` in my app. The problem is `hasAccess$` pipes through `filter()`, so that default never emits. Gave you an upvote though, I think startWith() will work great for some use-cases.